# I unable to handle bootstrap modal using Selenium with Java

Tags: selenium

Please tell me how to handle the Bootstrap modal, please open below link and click on **Launch modal** button of  **Single modal** example...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/bootstrap-modal-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Use css_selector as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.container-fluid.text-center > div > div.col-md-6.text-left > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.panel-body > a").click()
```

Comment: maintain clarity in your question for better understanding